# Is there any way to pass LinkButton content from one to another while redirecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass or store in Session Item clicked in GridView from one Page to another and passing the same parameter to my Stored Procedure to get data for the particular field.

I have created a grid view where data is coming from Store Procedure. 
One of the GridView fields is LinkButton. So on click of link button it should show all the details of the applicant in a new tab. The page is getting redirected but I am not able to store or pass particular field which is "APPL_REF_NO" as mention in code.

ASP Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvServiceApplication" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Data Found"
    Width="100%" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#facf5a"
    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" RowStyle-BackColor="White"
    RowStyle-ForeColor="Black">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ApplicationNo">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lblApplicationNo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("APPL_REF_NO") %>' OnClick="btnApplicantDetails_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>


protected void btnApplicantDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
          this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open
          ('ApplicantDetails.aspx','_blank');", true);
}


private void ApplicationDetailBind()
{
    try
    {
    DataTable dtApplicationDetail = new DataTable();
    dtApplicationDetail = objDepartmentWiseBA.getApplicantDetails(applicationnumber).Tables[0];
    gvApplicationIndetail.DataSource = dtApplicationDetail;
    gvApplicationIndetail.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         throw;
    }
}
```

We need to show application details based on parameter passed from LinkButton.
This paramters passed will again be used in StoredProcedure to bind another grid in ApplicantDetails Page. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just pass the param as a querystring?

Comment: Check out the answer that I just submitted. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following line in place of second line in link button click event.

The approach is to pass the desired value as a query string parameter to ApplicationDetails.aspx page. A query string parameter can then be easily obtained using the second code snippet.

*Second line in link button click event*

```
this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", 
 String.Format("window.open('ApplicantDetails.aspx?applRefNo={0}','_blank');", (sender as LinkButton).Text ), true);
```

Then in your destination page you can use following C# code to get the value of `APPL_REF_NO`.

*Get the value in destination page*

```
var applRefNoValue =  Request.QueryString["applRefNo"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the value in a session variable, I'd suggest to transmit the value as Request parameter to the page that is opened. So you'd have to extend the URL that is called with the refNo of the row:

```
protected void btnApplicantDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var refNo = ((LinkButton)sender).Text;
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('ApplicantDetails.aspx?ref_no=" + refNo + "','_blank');", true);
}
```

This approach does not use session state which might result in some hard to track bugs if the user clicks several of the pages. Each detail page that is opened receives the matching reference number.

In the detail page, you can use the `Request` object to read the parameter and fetch the corresponding data:

```
var refNo = Request["refNo"];
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

use onCommand event with command arguments, check the following code in the page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblApplicationNo" runat="server"
    Text='<%#Eval("APPL_REF_NO") %>'
    OnCommand="btnApplicantDetails_Command" CommandName="ApplicantDetails"
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("APPL_REF_NO") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

and the following in the code

```
protected void btnApplicantDetails_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string appNo = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    // do work ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
    Write as below
     <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ApplicationNo">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblApplicationNo" runat="server" 
       data-applRefNo='<%#Eval("APPL_REF_NO") %>' Text = "Application Details" OnClick="btnApplicantDetails_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>

   protected void btnApplicantDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      string applRefno = btnApplicantDetails.attr("data-applRefNo");
        your coding here
   }
```